# WPF Listbox selectedindex not working <no change>

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm a new in WPF. I have created a ListBox

```
<ListBox 
  Name="listBoxQuestion" 
  Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" 
  SelectionMode="Single" 
  MouseDown="listBoxQuestion_MouseDown" 
  SelectionChanged="listBoxQuestion_SelectionChanged" 
  DisplayMemberPath="Text">
</ListBox>
```

and I use **listBoxQuestion.SelectedIndex** to get index of selected item. But it only work **once**, the first time I click on item. When I click on **other item**, the index isn't changed. It still keep **current value**. I can't find what's wrong in my code. Please help me!

> Update

There are my itemsource

```
public class ListTopicBinding : ObservableCollection<Question>
{
}

ListQuestionBinding listQuestionShowing = new ListQuestionBinding();

listBoxQuestion.ItemsSource = listQuestionShowing;
```

When I create new item  I use code

```
Question q = new Question();
q.Text = "*";
listQuestionShowing.Add(q);
```

I have found that when I delete function in Question class

```
public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Text.GetHashCode();
    }
```

My ListBox work correctly. I wonder that how "**GetHashCode**" func affect **ListBox** in **WPF**. I used this code in **WinForm**, but nothing happened.
Sorry for my English

Comment: What is your code-behind?

Comment: Where is ItemsSource set?

Comment: Why would you bind to DisplayMemberPath in XAML but not ItemsSource.  Show your binding and implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Make ListTopicBinding a public property ( get ) and bind in xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Is it this you want?

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxQuestion.ItemsSource = new List<String> { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" };
    }

    private void listBoxQuestion_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You selected " + listBoxQuestion.SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Because it's not in the MVVM partern? 
Also, the question has changed quite allot since I gave my answer 11h ago...

Answer (score 0):

Names don't match up in the question

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=listTopicBinding}"
DisplayMemberPath="Text"

private ListTopicClass listTopicBinding = new ListTopicClass();
public ListTopicBinding 
{
   get { return listTopicBinding ; }
}
```